# Multithreading concepts on scala language

Tags: multithreading, scala

I dont know how to implement multithreading concept on scala language. Can any one suggest me how to implement & provide some samples for multithreading. Thank you

Comment: using `Future` is very popular http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: This is a very generic question. Can you give a simple multi-threaded example you would want to implement ?

Comment: This is not for what stackoverflow for. Try to google, look at `Future` as @ymonad suggested. You might also want to try `Akka` (though this is not multithreading, but it helps) for more complicated cases. If you hit any problem - you can return here and ask specific questions about the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options.

- [Scala Akka actor system](http://akka.io/)

> Akka is a toolkit and runtime
>   for building highly concurrent,
>   distributed, and resilient
>   message-driven applications
>   on the JVM.

- [Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

> Futures provide a way to reason about performing many operations in parallel– in an efficient and non-blocking way. A Future is a placeholder object for a value that may not yet exist. Generally, the value of the Future is supplied concurrently and can subsequently be used. Composing concurrent tasks in this way tends to result in faster, asynchronous, non-blocking parallel code.

- [Java Concurrency Model](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html#runnable)

> Scala concurrency is built on top of the Java concurrency model. On
>   Sun JVMs, with a IO-heavy workload, we can run tens of thousands of
>   threads on a single machine. A Thread takes a Runnable. You have to
>   call start on a Thread in order for it to run the Runnable.